# MVC3 accessing Repository in Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository

Thanks for the help!  My solution below has been updated to the correct answer.

I have a simple question on how to access the repository for my controller.  If you look at my addMovie method, I thought I could do movies.AddMovie(movie) inside the ModelState.IsValid after the controller inherits the IMovieRepository.

IMovieRepository:

```
public interface IMovieRepository : IDisposable
{
    IEnumerable<Movies> GetMovies();
    Movies GetMovieByID(int id);
    void AddMovie(Movies movie);
    void UpdateMovie(Movies movie);
    void DeleteMovie(int id);
    void save(Movies movie);
}
```

MovieRepository:

```
public class MovieRepository : BaseRepository, IMovieRepository
{
    private MovieContext db;

    public MovieRepository(MovieContext repo)
    {
        db = repo;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Movies> GetMovies()
    {
        return db.Movies.ToList();
    }

    public Movies GetMovieByID(int id)
    {
        return db.Movies.Find(id);
    }

    public void AddMovie(Movies movie)
    {
        db.Movies.Add(movie);
    }

    public void UpdateMovie(Movies movie)
    {
        db.Entry(movie).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void DeleteMovie(int id)
    {
        Movies movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
        db.Movies.Remove(movie);
    }

    public void save(Movies movie)
    {
        if (movie.movieID == 0)
            db.Movies.Add(movie);
        else
            db.Entry<Movies>(movie).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

NinjectDependencyResolve:

```
Bind<IMovieRepository>().To<MovieRepository>();
```

MoviesController:

```
public class MoviesController : Controller
{
    private IMovieRepository movieRepository;

    public MoviesController()
    {
        this.movieRepository = new MovieRepository(new MovieContext());
    }

    public MoviesController(IMovieRepository movieRepository)
    {
        this.movieRepository = movieRepository;
    }
    #region "GET"
    //
    // GET: /Admin/Movies/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    #endregion

    #region "POST"
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult addMovie(Movies movie)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            movieRepository.AddMovie(movie);
            movieRepository.save(movie);
            return RedirectToAction("index", "movies");
        }
        return View(movie);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: You should not change your question to your solution.  That does not allow others to benefit from the question/answer.  If you want to include the answer, then add it to the end of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a constructor to the controller:

```
private IMovieRepository _Repository;

[Inject]
public MovieController(IMovieRepository repository)
{
    _Repository = repository;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!  What does the [Inject] do?

Comment: Since you're using Ninject, you need the attribute so Ninject knows where the dependency injection occurs. Otherwise, you'll get an error saying you need a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
private IMovieRepository _repository;

public MoviesController(IMovieRepository repository)
{
  _repository =repository; 
}
```

use constructor injection